# Mousedown still submitting form, when it should not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

hello i have a login validation form which uses a mix of jquery and ajax to do validations... if the values are ok the form should submit, if the values are not ok then the form should not submit... however in my case the form is submitting even when the values are incorrect ( i am using the mousedown function ) please see below my code..

```
<form method="post" name="loginform" action="models/login.php">
    <input type="email" class="homepage" name="user_email2" id="user_email2" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50" />
    <div class="errormsg" id="errormsg6"></div>
    <input type="password" class="homepage" name="user_password2" id="user_password2" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20" />
    <div class="errormsg" id="errormsg7"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Submit">
    <div class="errormsglast" id="errormsg8"></div>
</form>
```

jquery and ajax

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    /* ----------------- Login Validations Global Variables -----------------   */
    var user_email2 = "";
    var user_emailajax2 = "";
    var user_password2 = "";
    var user_passwordajax2 = "";
    var emailformat = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);

    /* ----------------- Define Validate Email */
    var validate_email_login = function()
    {
        var item5 = $("#user_email2").val().toLowerCase();
        if (item5.length < 6 || item5.length > 50)
        {
            $("#errormsg6").html("Email : 6 - 50 Characters");
            user_email2 = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $("#errormsg6").html("");
            user_email2 = item5;
            if (!emailformat.test(item5))
            {
                $("#errormsg6").html("Wrong Email Format");
                user_email2 = "";
            }
            else
            {
                $("#errormsg6").html("");
                user_email2 = item5;
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'classes/validatelogin.php?f=1',
                    data: "user_email2=" + item5,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        if (msg == "ok")
                        {
                            user_emailajax2 = "";
                            $("#errormsg6").html("Email Does Not Exist");
                        }
                        else if (msg == "exists")
                        {
                            user_emailajax2 = item5;
                            $("#errormsg6").html("");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    /* ----------------- Define Validate Password */
    var validate_password_login = function()
    {
        var item5 = $("#user_email2").val().toLowerCase();
        var item6 = $("#user_password2").val();

        if (item6.length < 8 || item6.length > 20)
        {
            $("#errormsg7").html("Password : 8-20 Characters");
            user_password2 = "";
        }
        else
        {
            $("#errormsg7").html("");
            user_password2 = item6;
            if (user_email2 != "" && user_emailajax2 != "")
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "classes/validatelogin.php?f=2",
                    data: "user_email2=" + item5 + "&user_password2=" + item6,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        if (msg == "WrongPw")
                        {
                            user_passwordajax2 = "";
                            $("#errormsg7").html("Wrong Password - See Forgot Password");
                        }
                        else if (msg == "CorrectPw")
                        {
                            user_passwordajax2 = item6;
                            $("#errormsg7").html("");
                            /* window.location.href="manage-properties"; */
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }




    /* ----------------- Run Functions */
    $("#user_email2").on('focusout', validate_email_login);
    $("#user_password2").on('focusout', validate_password_login);


    /* ----------------- Stop on Submit */
    $( "#login" ).mousedown(function() 
    {
        validate_email_login();
        validate_password_login();


        if (user_email2 == "" || user_emailajax2 == "" || user_password2 == "" || user_passwordajax2 == "")
        {
            $("#errormsg8").html("Please Fill All Fields (Correctly)");
            console.log("submit false");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#errormsg8").html("");
            console.log("submit true");
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

**Solution Tried** - problem is that when user puts the wrong event that is fine, but if user then puts the correct values, the submit returns false on first time, then second time it returns true... it should return true in first go

```
<input type="button" name="login" id="login" value="Submit">

    $( "#login" ).mousedown(function() 
    {
        validate_email_login();
        validate_password_login();


        if (user_email2 == "" || user_emailajax2 == "" || user_password2 == "" || user_passwordajax2 == "")
        {
            $("#errormsg8").html("Please Fill All Fields (Correctly)");
            console.log("submit false");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#errormsg8").html("");
            console.log("submit true");
            $('[name=loginform]').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Whats your use case for this code ?
Are you trying to learn JS ? 
Or do you need a working solution for a production site, and just tried copy pasting some stuff you found online ?

If your learning JS you should go over accessing the DOM, Submitting forms and handling asynchronous code.

Comment: i am using this code already in production, i watched tutorials on youtube and wrote the code, i will look into sync async as mentioned by you... my proficiency level is that of a beginner...   the function works ok if you replace focusout with keyup, and mousedown with click

Comment: I've wrote an answer you might find useful, but I would suggest keep learning JS and web development before writing production code

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having a type="submit" button just have a normal button e.g`<input type="button" name="login" id="login" value="Submit">`. Then when you finished checking the values and happy that it should send then just call:

```
$('[name=loginform]').submit();
```

Because what is happening currently is that the form submits when you click on the button, because you are not stopping that event from happening.

If you want to prevent the form from submitting I would suggest either not using that button and initiating the submit yourself like I mentioned above, or alternatively you can use the onsubmit="someFunction()" on the form element way and just return false if it should not submit and return true if it should.

Comment: @DragonFire It is because your ajax calls have not finished on your first click. That is a different problem and would need some restructuring. I would suggest creating a new question for that.

Comment: i have already done that please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896084/jquery-ajax-on-focusout-on-submit-requires-2-clicks

Comment: @DragonFire Ok... I think it might be a good idea to talk to me in a chatroom, I think that would be best... Can you join a stackoverflow chatroom yet?

Comment: yes i can join chat room, when conversation is long it gives me option

Comment: right now conversation is not long enough, is there any other way

Comment: any luck with finding a solution

Answer (score 1):

I would say your code suffers from a few issues and some bad practices.
I see you are trying to learn JS so forgive me for not directly solving your issue but to give you some pointers and point you to some best practices.

1. #### Logic -

   It seems like you are doing a login form. I would say most of this checks should not happen in the client but on the server. 
   When user signups it might be wise to check user name length on the client as well and prompt the user that he can't use the user name he wants to register with, but during login all the client care is can I login or not.
2. #### Security -

   You seem to have two serious security issues with your code

   1. You allow to test if an e-mail/user exist or not using 'classes/validatelogin.php?f=1'. in general you should always test the user and password together if they exist and match the user should be able to login, if not the login should fail. you shouldn't notify the user why it fails (if the user name does not exist or if it exist but the password is wrong).
   2. You don't seem to hash passwords in the database. I assume it by limiting the password max length. let the user choose as long password as he wants and hash it using a secure hashing algorithm (I'd suggest bcrypt but google around and find a suitable one). I know you are only learning but this is highly important I think hashing is the first thing you need to learn when handling user logins
3. #### Working with the DOM.

   You should cache your DOM elements
   so instead of calling $('#id') all the time in the main function scope set

   ```
   var emailInput = $("#user_email2");  
   function submitForm() {
       var email = emailInput.val().toLowerCase();
       ...
   }
   ```

   You should also probably set the `text` value of the element and not the `html` doesn't matter much now but since you are setting text value its good practice and will help you avoid unexpected injections and errors.
4. Since your using ajax you should not let the form to submit itself even when validation is successful.
5. #### Common logic should be packed into functions and reused.

   There are many places where your original code can be split into shorter and reusable functions
6. #### handle async code better

   jQuery supports the Promise API when using ajax requests, I would rather use it. Your original code had a few async calls if you needed to sync between them it would have been painful using plain callbacks (and it is probably what caused you issues in the first place)

Here is a simplified solution using my suggestions -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    var emailInput = $("#user_email2"),
        emailError = $("#errormsg6"),
        passwordInput = $("#user_password2"),
        passwordError = $("#errormsg7");  

    function required (value) {
        if (value) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        //this is just to make the code clear you could use 
        //`return value ? true : false` or  `return !!value`
    }

    $('form:eq(0)').on('submit', function (e) {
        var valid = true,
            email = emailInput.val(),
            password = passwordInput.val();

        e.preventDefault();

        if ( !required(email) ) {
            emailError.text('Email is required');
            valid = false;
        }

        if ( !required(password) ) {
            passwordError.text('Password is required');
            valid = false;
        }

        if ( valid ) {

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                data: {
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                }
            }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //redirect user to main page
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //show the user the error
            })

        }
    });
});
```