# How to properly defer dom element change until event handler execution in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

**foo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="tdTxtBox"><input type="text" id="txtBox"/></td>
            <td id="tdChkBox"><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script src="foo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**foo.js**

```
$('#txtBox').on('blur', function(){
    console.log('came out of text box');
});

$('#chkBox').on('click',function(){
    console.log('checked check box');
});
```

**Normal flow**: Enter a value in the text box, click on the checkbox, which actually triggers both 'blur' on the text box and 'click' on the check box. This outputs:

```
came out of text box
checked check box
```

On Changing **foo.js** like so:

```
$('#txtBox').on('blur', function(){
    console.log('came out of text box');
    $('#tdChkBox').html('<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox"/>');
});

$('#chkBox').on('click',function(){
    console.log('checked check box');
});
```

This outputs:

```
came out of text box
```

It makes sense because on `blur` i actually reset the `#tdChkBox` with another set of dom elements, jquery looses track of the raised event `click` for the checkbox(is this correct understanding?)

I found a fix for this issue in one the SO Post, to defer change of html using `setTimeout`, which will let the `click` event handler execute like so:

**foo.js**

```
$('#txtBox').on('blur', function(){
    console.log('came out of text box');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#tdChkBox').html('<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox"/>');
    },100);
});

$('#chkBox').on('click',function(){
    console.log('checked check box');
});
```

Here lies the problem, the *100* ms for `setTimeout` works, but *0* ms doesn't work. Apparently it took time *T* for the *system* to raise the click event and register it to *jquery event queue*. The time assigned to `setTimeout` has to be greater than *T*.

This solution is not full proof. What if tomorrow, it takes more than *100* ms? If i increase this time to let's say *1000* ms, its a usability hit.

How to properly approach this problem? Is the understanding correct here or am i missing something fundamental?

In case this is a standard jquery/javascript problem, can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`mousedown`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjg3ICbn6nUAhXMQo8KHeKSDhoQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fmousedown%2F&usg=AFQjCNEYvWdRcdulubzp2M72EIJe3FJVZg&sig2=n-HvKpKR_duz4K3IVRen1g) instead click .its execute before `blur`.`Blur` run on `mouseup` that means clicked completed

```
$('#txtBox').on('blur', function(){
    console.log('came out of text box');
});

$('#chkBox').on('mousedown',function(){
    console.log('checked check box');
});
```

**Working example**

```js
$('#txtBox').on('blur', function() {
  console.log('came out of text box');
});

$('#chkBox').on('mousedown', function() {
  console.log('checked check box');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="tdTxtBox"><input type="text" id="txtBox" /></td>
    <td id="tdChkBox"><input type="checkbox" id="chkBox" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is useful. Can you give some references about this? What's the order of event raise?

Comment: see this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652852/jquery-fire-click-before-blur-event and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084780/how-should-i-fire-javascript-blur-event-after-click-event-that-causes-the-blur